# Data for plotting phase changes in water

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, water, phase-transition, phase-diagram

I want to plot phase diagrams of water that show its **density**, **heat capacity**, and **entropy** as it undergoes various first order (discontinuous) phase transitions with increasing temperature. I'm particularly interested in the regions where water undergoes melting ($\sim 0^\circ C$) and boiling ($\sim 100^\circ C$).

For example, this phase diagram shows density vs temperature as water goes from solid to liquid, but I can't find the reference at the bottom of the image:

[image]

What are some data references / tables that show values of density, heat capacity, and entropy vs water temperature? (I'm assuming that other parameters, e.g. pressure, can be kept constant.)

Comment: Get yourself a copy of the steam tables.

Comment: The actual references are likely found at the back of the chapter (or book) that this figure is taken from.

Comment: @JonCuster Do you know the title of the reference(s)?